# Canon xf105 blending frames at 24p?

Tags: video

I just finished shooting some film on a Canon xf105 in 1080p24 on the 50mb/s setting with a shutter of 48. Every few frames it seems to be doubling the image, reminds me of deinterlaced blended frame. What is happening? I have twiked the fps playback in premiere thinking it is trying to convert up to a higher frame rate, but everything is 23.976 fps and it still does it. Could this be an effect of the rolling shutter on the camera? or maybe the camera does not capture true 24p and it is interpolating frames for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

The XF-105 will acquire native 24p video, that is 23.97 fps.
3:2 pulldown is only added to the Composite/YUV and SD/HD-SDI signal interfaces during 24p, and 2:2 pulldown during 30p.

Can you upload the video seq somewhere, and I'll have a look at it for you.